# Error (TypeError: unhashable type) en python

Tags: python

Alguien me explica de que trata ese error porfavor:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Este es todo el codigo para que lo prueben y me digan que esta mal:

```
def buscar_cumpleaños(cumpleaños):
    persona = input("\n Ingrese la fecha de cumpleaños de la persona:")
    cumple_2 = cumpleaños.get(cumpleaños)
    
    if cumple_2:
        print(f"Cumpleaños encontrado: ")
        print(f"Cumpleaños: {persona['cumple']}")
        print(f"----------------------")
       # print(f"Persona '{persona['Persona']}' agregada correctamente. ")
    else:
        print(f"No se ha encontrado el cumpleaños {persona} en la lista.")
```

No entiendo nada del por que se da ese error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! recibis un objeto cumpleaños, que llama a un get de un objeto cumpleaños, y le pasa como parametro cumpleaños??? no soy experto.. pero suena raro...

Comment: Lo se pero asi me lo piden en el ejercicio

Comment: Podrias ayudarme?

Comment: no se python lo suficiente como para ayudarte.. pero seguro, queres buscar el nombre que te acaban de ingresar en el arreglo de cumpleaños.. no????

Comment: si esoo es lo que ocupo

Comment: seguro que esta: cumple_2 = cumpleaños.get(cumpleaños) no deberia ser cumple_2 = cumpleaños.get(persona) ????

Comment: ya intente asi y no logro que me de los datos

Comment: y esto que es?? {persona['cumple']}

Comment: Es la forma que debe de aparecer en la terminal pero voy a hacer algo y te digo si lo logro

Comment: persona es una cadena... la vas a indexar como un diccionario???

Comment: Mira te explico ocupo que me lea los datos de un archivo .json que es donde se guardan todos los datos de las personas

Comment: Si eso es lo que ocupo

Comment: ponele comentarios a tu codigo, y vas a ver todas las cosas que no tienen sentido en el....

Comment: no entendi lo que dijiste

Comment: si te paso el codigo podrias revisarlo y decirme que esta mal en el ?

Comment: Lo que quiere decir gbianchi, y tiene razón, es que mires lo que hace el código paso a paso. Si hacés eso, vas a notar que el código no funcionaría bien por muchas razones. Estás tratando de obtener en cumpleaños.get(cumpleaños) el valor asociado al propio diccionario de cumpleaños. El diccionario de cumpleaños está dentro de si mismo? persona es el nombre de una persona, al poner entre corchetes algo al lado, intentás obtener la letra número "cumple". Y si incluso lo anterior no sucediese, el print en el else mostraría, si ingreso Juan, "no se ha encontrado el cumpleaños Juan en la lista"

Comment: Te recomiendo reescribir el código poco a poco y pensarlo con detenimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías pasar el código completo?

Lo que yo creo es que cumpleaños no es un diccionario. por que no tiene método GET
intenta hacer esto:

```
def buscar_cumpleaños(cumpleaños):
    persona = input("\n Ingrese la fecha de cumpleaños de la persona:")
    cumple_2 = cumpleaños[persona]
    
    if cumple_2:
        print(f"Cumpleaños encontrado: ")
        print(f"Cumpleaños: {cumpleaños[persona]}")
        print(f"----------------------")
    else:
        print(f"No se ha encontrado el cumpleaños {persona} en la lista.")


cumple = {'13-FEB-1991': 'FELIPE'}

buscar_cumpleaños(cumple)
```